# Making aligned environment and stacked limits work

Tags: spacing, align

I'm trying to typeset something like this:

```
      \begin{align*}
    n^{\frac1n}
    & =
      \exp\left(\frac1n\ln(n)\right)
    \\
    & =
      \exp\left(\frac1n\ln(n)\right)
    \\
    & \mathop{\sim}_{n\rightarrow+\infty}
      1
  \end{align*}
```

Hélas, the operators are left aligned with respect to their width, so the \sim ends up too much on the right because the limits make it appear wider.

How can I get a better alignment without adding space around the other operators by hand ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `\mathclap` from [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) and then add some space before the limit value:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usefonttheme[only math]{serif}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
n^{\frac{1}{n}}
&= \exp\Bigl(\frac{1}{n}\ln(n)\Bigr) \\
&= \exp\Bigl(\frac{1}{n}\ln(n)\Bigr) \\
&\mathop{\sim}_{\mathclap{n\rightarrow+\infty}}\quad 1
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also changed `\left` `\right` pairs for `\Bigl`, `\Bigr` which are, in my opinion, enough and better.

Another variants in which \xrightarrow was used instead of \sim (the former seesm more usual to indicate the value of a limit):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usefonttheme[only math]{serif}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
n^{\frac{1}{n}}
&= \exp\Bigl(\frac{1}{n}\ln(n)\Bigr) \\
&= \exp\Bigl(\frac{1}{n}\ln(n)\Bigr) \\
&\xrightarrow[\mathclap{n\rightarrow+\infty}]{}\quad 1
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
n^{\frac{1}{n}}
&= \exp\Bigl(\frac{1}{n}\ln(n)\Bigr) \\
&= \exp\Bigl(\frac{1}{n}\ln(n)\Bigr) \\
&\xrightarrow[n\rightarrow+\infty]{} 1
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
n^{\frac{1}{n}}
&= \exp\Bigl(\frac{1}{n}\ln(n)\Bigr) \\
&= \exp\Bigl(\frac{1}{n}\ln(n)\Bigr) \xrightarrow[n\rightarrow+\infty]{} 1
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]